# DAX Get historical data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get the "Value" of a record with the maximum value of "HistoryId" (grouped by "groupId") among the records up to a certain date.
The date value is a variable value.

groupTable

| GroupId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| k1 | Group 1 |
| k2 | Group 2 |

historyTable

| HistoryId | GroupId | Created | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | k1 | 2023-01-20 | 1 |
| 2 | k1 | 2023-01-21 | 8 |
| 3 | k1 | 2023-01-22 | 3 |
| 4 | k2 | 2023-01-20 | 11 |
| 5 | k2 | 2023-01-21 | 28 |
| 6 | k2 | 2023-01-21 | 33 |

calendar

| Date |
| --- |
| 2023-01-01 |
| ... |
| 2023-12-31 |

**Expected results**

for 2023-01-20

| GroupId | Value |
| --- | --- |
| k1 | 1 |
| k2 | 11 |

for 2023-01-21

| GroupId | Value |
| --- | --- |
| k1 | 8 |
| k2 | 33 |

for 2023-01-22

| GroupId | Value |
| --- | --- |
| k1 | 3 |
| k2 | 33 |

I planned to make a metric, but this option did not work.

```
    _m = 
    var sd = selectedvalue(_calendar[Date])
    var mft = filter(historyTable, [Created] < sd)
    var res = summarizecolumns(
        historyTable[GroupId],
        mft,
        "HistoryValue", calculate(values(historyTable[ToNumberValue]), historyTable[HistoryId] = max(historyTable[HistoryId]))
    )
    return sumx(res, [HistoryValue])
```

Could you help me solve this problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is this measure:

```
Value for max historyid group and date = 
VAR values_per_date =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES('Date'[Date]),
        "Value", 
        VAR max_history_id =
            CALCULATE(
                max(History[HistoryId]),
                'Date'[Date] <= max('Date'[Date]),
                REMOVEFILTERS('Date')
            )
        VAR tmp = CALCULATE(
            SUM(History[Value]),
            History[HistoryId] = max_history_id,
            'Date'[Date] <= max('Date'[Date]),
            REMOVEFILTERS('Date')
        )
        RETURN tmp
    )
VAR _result =
    SUMX(
        values_per_date,
        [Value]
    )
RETURN _result
```

[image: result]

[image: datamodel]